# Can spams see/use javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, spam

My question is obvious. Can spams (I mean blog spams) make use of javascript on my site?

For example "Laravel" needs csrf code on forms. If I pass csrf code as a javascript variable and append the code using jquery append method into the form, will spams be able to submit the form?

Comment: What do you mean by `spam` ? If you are the site owner then either its advertisment that you have for your blog or probably some XSS attack. The later has malicious behavious but you are pretty safe with former. Also just to be sure all spam is not XSS.

Comment: @georoot I do not know much about spams. I am developing a cms where users can register and post blog, comment etc. I know a social network script that so many spams register and post blogs (it is an advertiesement as you mentioned). Sometimes even captcha cannot prevent them. I just do not want my script to allow spams like this.

Comment: Okay so what you are refering to is bots basically. They are not harfull in anyway to your website except the cluttered content and `no` they can't access you js unless you have not protected against `XSS` which is most common attack vector for script kiddies.

Comment: Spam is generally a piece of text. As far as I know, advertising texts do not have eyes or built in parsers. I think you mean spambots :)

Comment: In the end, you can create an artificial intelligence powered kiborg that itself uses a legitimate browser on a legitimate machine to spread spam everywhere. Unlikely? Sure, but not impossible. Same with regular spam-bots: _some_ of the are capable of evaluating JavaScript, but not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, as the source code is on the client side, they can either run it, alter it before running it, or reverse engineer it and populate the form field with the required value directly. That's why any spam protection mechanism always need a server side parte. Otherwise you're just making it harder to break... That said, think if the result is worth the effort to reverse engineer your spam protection.

Answer (score 1):

So, our company has been developing anti-spam for websites and I can say that many spambots(about 30%) are able to use javascript.